# pg_query returns NULL even though SQL query works correctly in pgAdminIII

Tags: php, postgresql

**The Problem**

The following code returns "queried...NULL" (assume that `$id` is always a 6-digit number)

```
$id = sprintf("%06d", $id);
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT first_name, last_name
        FROM schemaname.tablename
        WHERE person_id='.$id;
$q = pg_query($sql) or die(pg_last_error().' '.$sql);
print 'queried...';
$items = pg_fetch_all($q) or die(pg_last_error().' '.var_export($q, true));
print 'fetched...';
exit(0);
```

Note: `person_id` is an `integer not null`

**What I Have Tried**

- The query works correctly in pgAdminIII when I type in the 6-digit id number to replace `$id`
- The php pg connection grants the connected user `USAGE` rights on `schemaname.tablename`
- read [php pg_query not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704649/php-pg-query-not-working)
- read [pg_query returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880830/pg-query-returns-nothing)
- I tried my code both with and without the `sprintf` statement ([php images rename double digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253113/php-images-rename-double-digits/15253153#15253153))

Answer (score 0):

All of your testing so far looks like it has occurred on the PHP side.  The immediate question is what is happening on the PostgreSQL side.  My bet would be something like:

1. The query is not what you think it is.
2. PostgreSQL is not getting what you think it is getting.
3. Something else.

The first thing to do is to log in with pgadmin and run the following utility statement:

```
ALTER USER [app username] SET log_statements=all;
```

Then run your PHP script and check what PostgreSQL is actually receiving.  You can then run the statements from the log in pgAdmin to check.  You may find, for example, that your sprintf is not doing what you think it is doing or there is a typo in your query somewhere.

When you are done you can:

```
 ALTER USER [app username] RESET log_statements;
```

Answer (score -2):

You aren't connecting to the database.  You need to create a database connection and then pass the handler of that connection to pg_query()

```
$conn = pg_pconnect("dbname=publisher");
if (!$conn) {
    echo "An error occurred.\n";
    exit;
}

$id = sprintf("%06d", $id);
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT first_name, last_name
        FROM schemaname.tablename
        WHERE person_id='.$id;
$q = pg_query($conn, $sql) or die(pg_last_error().' '.$sql);
print 'queried...';
$items = pg_fetch_all($q) or die(pg_last_error().' '.var_export($q, true));
print 'fetched...';
exit(0);
```

Comment: There was a pg_connect which I elided from the source code for security reasons and indirectly mentioned in the "what I have tried" section.